# Spectral Measures: Integration of Product

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and spectral a measure $E:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

Define the integral of simple functions by:
$$\int_\Omega s\mathrm{d}E:=\sum_{z\in\mathbb{C}}z\cdot E(s^{-1}z)\quad(s:\Omega\to\mathbb{C})$$ and extend it to the uniform closure:
$$\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}E:=\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\int_\Omega s_\lambda\mathrm{d}E\quad(s_\lambda\stackrel{\infty}{\to}f)$$
This goes fine as:
$$\|\int_\Omega s\mathrm{d}Ex\|^2=\ldots\leq\|s\|_\infty^2\cdot\sum\|E(A_k)x\|^2=\ldots\leq\|s\|_\infty^2\cdot\|x\|^2$$

How to prove then that it respects multiplication:
$$\int_\Omega fg\mathrm{d}E=\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}E\cdot\int_\Omega g\mathrm{d}E$$

The problem I'm having is that I hardly even can imagine this to hold for the Lebesgue integral:
$$\int_\Omega fg\mathrm{d}µ=\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}µ\cdot\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}µ$$

Comment: Note that Lebesgue measure is not an example of a spectral measure.  Indeed, it would be a good exercise to show from the definition that any spectral measure taking its values in $\mathbb{C}$ (so that $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}$) is a point mass.  (And in fact, you can easily verify that Lebesgue measure does not in general respect multiplication.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Is it because they're projections and the complex numbers being one dimensional?

Comment: @Freeze_S : In what $\infty$ norm are you thinking of $s_{\lambda} \rightarrow f$? Without that specific, how are you going to argue convergence in $\mathcal{B}(H)$?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Are you aware that if $E(S)\ne E(T)$, that $\|E(S)-E(T)\|\ge 1$ is common? The spectral measure is highly discontinuous in the uniform operator topology, even if you don't have atoms. I think you need to be working in the strong operator topology, not the uniform topology.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I think that part is fine.  It's not hard to check from the definition that for simple functions $s : \Omega \to \mathcal{B}(H)$, we have $\left\Vert \int s\,dE \right\Vert \le \|s\|_{\infty}$.  Thus if $s_{\lambda} \to f$ uniformly (i.e. in $\infty$ norm) then $\int s_{\lambda}\,dE$ is Cauchy in operator norm and hence norm convergent.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Actually, I think for my comment to be true, we need some assumption on $\Omega$, such as that it is standard Borel.  But suppose $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and recall from the definition that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $E(A) E(B) = 0$.  When $E$ is scalar valued this means that given any two disjoint sets, one of them has measure zero.  You can now identify a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ that has measure 1, for example as the infimum of all $x$ such that $E((-\infty, x]) = 1$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: In fact, on closer inspection, not only is it "not hard to check" but it's exactly what is proved in the question's third displayed equation.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yes I'm aware of that but for the construction it's fine as one uses uniform convergence. For pointwise convergence you're right and one has to use the strong topology. All in one (and I really like that characterization) one can say with caution that $f_\lambda\to f$ uniformly implies $f_\lambda(T)\to f(T)$ uniformly whereas $f_n\to f$ pointwise implies $f_n(T)\to f(T)$ pointwise (where of course uniformly for operators should not be taken literally but in the sense of operator topology).

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hmm I'm trying to arrange your argument but having two left hands right now: So I start that since the complex numbers are one dimensional there can be at most one nontrivial projector. The problem is to detect it now...

Comment: @NateEldredge : You say $\infty$ norm, but that normally implies with respect to a specific measure and that's why I asked which measure. You could mean with respect to a specific $\mu_{x}(S)=\|E(S)x\|^{2}$ or you could mean with respect to $E(S)$, which is a little non-standard. If he meant with respect to a measure, then I thought that should be spelled out. Otherwise $\sup$ is probably the correct term.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Oh no no big missunderstanding - maybe my notation was confusing - I simply meant in the uniform topology ;)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Wait isn't it simply that in the complex case it can't happen $E(A)\neq 0$ and $E(B)\neq 0$ for disjoints $A\cap B=\varnothing$. That gives especially for all $\omega\in\Omega$ either $E(\{\omega\})=0$ or $E(\{\omega\}^c)=0$. Hmm but then still it lacks an argument...

Comment: @T.A.E.: Oh I see the confusion.  I think it's not unusual to refer to the supremum or uniform norm as the $\infty$ norm, when it is clear from context that you don't mean the $L^\infty$ norm with respect to a particular measure.  (Of course one could think of the uniform norm as the $L^\infty$ norm with respect to counting measure.)

Comment: @Freeze_S: That just tells you the measure is either a point mass or atomless.  You have to work harder to exclude the second case.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Right just noticed it ...so what to do then?

Comment: @Freeze_S: Read the rest of my earlier comment :-)

Comment: @Freeze_S: In fact by a similar argument you can show that if $\mathcal{H}$ has finite dimension $n$, then any spectral measure on $\mathbb{R}$ or any other Polish space is supported on a finite set of size at most $n$ (corresponding to the at most $n$ eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix).

Comment: @NateEldredge: For general measure space I guess one would be tempted to detect that point by constructing nested balls all of nonvanishing mass, but does this work as for non first countable spaces?

Comment: @Freeze_S: No, it doesn't.  A counterexample would be an uncountable $\Omega$ with the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable sets, and a measure that gives measure 0 to the former and 1 to the latter.  Or the Dieudonne measure on $[0, \omega_1]$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: 1st countability is not enough as - sry I got to go as my roomies want to party ^^

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sorry for the disruption yesterday. Now I thought a little bit about it and came to the following possible counterexample: Let $E(A)=1$ if $(-\infty,b]\subseteq A$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $E(A)=0$ else. Then it is a spectral measure but not a point mass.

Comment: @Freeze_S: That $E$ isn't countably (or even finitely) additive.  Note that $E(\mathbb{Q})=E(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ but $E(\mathbb{R}) = 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Are you sure that a spectral measure into the complex numbers as Hilbert space must be a point mass? I think the only thing which is for sure is that it has precisely one atom but not necessarily that atom is a point. Consider for example the spectral measure defined by the cumulative distribution function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}):F(x>0)\equiv1, F(x\leq0)\equiv0$ and $E(-\infty,x]:=F(x)$. That one is a spectral measure has an atom around zero but is not a point mass as $F(0)=0$...

Comment: @Freeze_S: Your $F$ is not a cumulative distribution function as it is not continuous from the right.  And if you try to use it to define $E$ as stated, you will again find it is not countably additive.  The intervals $(1/n, \infty)$ all have measure 0, so countable additivity forces $E((0,\infty)) = 0$.  Since $E((-\infty, 0]) = 0$ also this cannot be reconciled with $E(\mathbb{R})=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: suppose first that $f,g$ are simple functions.  Verify that $f,g$ can be written as
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}, \qquad g = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i 1_{A_i}$$
for some common collection of measurable sets $\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$, which moreover can be taken to be pairwise disjoint.

Then expand the product in $\int fg\,dE$ and recall the property $E(A) E(B) = 0$ when $A,B$ are disjoint.  That will get rid of the cross terms.